# Service to periodically load data to BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, buffer, bigdata

I noticed that the billing of our project on Google BigQuery is dominated by the cost of the resource `StreamingBytes` (90% of the total cost). This is due to the fact that we stream one record at a time by using the `insertAll()` method. In fact, the data inserted per day is in the order of 100GB, but we are charged for about 10 times that (~1TB), because BigQuery considers each row to be minimum 1KB and we push many rows of small size.

Changing the schema of the tables in order to make them more "horizontal" would be a solution to reduce the cost, but it would be not convenient for the way our pipelines are designed.

Instead, we wanted to exploit the fact that loading data to BigQuery from files (POST request) or from Google Cloud Storage is free and that we don't need immediate access to the data. We want to create a service that "buffers" rows coming from different machines (Celery workers in particular) and periodically loads batches of rows to BigQuery via loading from files.

> First question: is there a service that does the same already?

When it comes to the implementation, we were thinking of using a relational database (i.e. PostgreSQL) to store the buffered data so that we can exploit the way it handles concurrent transactions. An in-memory storage (like Redis) would be too expensive for such use case. Can you think of a better solution?

> Where should I store data in the buffer service?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is a good fit for Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow.  Beam is pretty well suited to taking PCollections of records and appending them to BigQuery tables.  For example, see this sample from the Apache Beam github repo:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/bigquery_schema.py

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dan. I am not sure I understand though. What would the Beam pipeline do in my case? I would still need some sort of shared filesystem or database to use as a buffer, wouldn't I?

Comment: The Beam pipeline would orchestrate the loading of files from wherever you staged them.  For simplicity, you could stage the incoming data in either Google Cloud PubSub or Google Cloud Storage, with the former probably being the simplest fit.  Here's a project which is [celery-like and publishes to PubSub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/psq).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that can fit your case is a tool called Alooma.

It can read and replicate all of the data in files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket into BigQuery. You won't need to create a buffer service for this solution, your data will be loaded directly into BigQuery

https://www.alooma.com/integrations/to/bigquery

Files in your Google Cloud Storage bucket can be packaged and compressed using Tar or GZip, and can contain either one event per line, a single JSON object, or an array of JSON objects.

Check this out for more information on how to connect Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery:

https://support.alooma.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001940489-Google-Cloud-Storage-integration

Full Disclosure: I used to work as an Software Engineer at Alooma